# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I integrated `react-leaflet` on my project create with `create-react-app` scripts. I follow this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/e3zh51fp/7/).

Everything works, but when I try use `GeoJson`component imported as:

```
import { Map, TileLayer, Popup, GeoJson } from 'react-leaflet'
```

I have the following warning.

> warning.js:35 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in. Check your code at
>   index.js:47.

and error

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Leaflet`

and I can't see the region on maps.

How can fix this? 
Thanks
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to react-leaflet recent changes , 
You should try to import `GeoJSON` instead of `GeoJson`.
It was changed in order to match the recent leaflet library change.